# Get value of custom attribute with c# from the code behind file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, attributes

I've the code below where I dynamically give the div a value for the attribute "data-order". I'd like be able to grab this value with c# from the code behind file, but I unfortunately cant figure out how to do it.

```
<asp:ListView ID="display_backlog" runat="server" DataSourceID="get_backlog" DataKeyNames="story_id">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <p>There is no stories in the product backlog for this project.</p>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row" CssClass="sortable-item" runat="server" data-order="" data-id='<%# Eval("story_id") %>'>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="panel">
                        <p><asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("story_title") %>' runat="server" ID="story_titleLabel" /></p> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholderContainer" style=""><span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" /></div>
        <div style="">
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to add a hidden input server control to the page and to set the value of that hidden input dynamically when you set the value of the "data-order" attribute.  You can then get the value of the hidden input easily from the code behind (because it's a server control) whenever you submit the form, as long as the hidden server control is in the form.